# How do I link SDL .a files with GCC?

Tags: gcc, sdl

Not a duplicate; Answers on various forums didn't fix the problem.
I am running GCC through commands and I am getting undefined references from SDL even though it appears like I linked SDL correctly, how do I stop from getting those undefined references ?
I do not get undefined references from mingw, just SDL.

This is my command: (all the libraries are being located by GCC from what I can tell)

```
gcc main.c ^
-o app.exe ^
-I "C:\__coding\tools\SDL2-2.0.10\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2" ^
-L "C:\__coding\tools\MinGW\lib\" ^
-l "libmingw32.a" ^
-L "C:\__coding\tools\SDL2-2.0.10\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" ^
-l "libSDL2main.a" ^
-l "libSDL2.a"
```

This is the output:

```
C:...\main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to 'SDL_Init'
C:...\main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to 'SDL_Quit'
c:/__coding/tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqsLSRk.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section '.eh_frame'
c:/__coding/tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.c includes SDL.h and just runs SDL_Init() and SDL_Quit().
I also get the classic undefined reference to "winmain" when I remove SDL_Init() and SDL_Quit().
Thanks alot.

Comment: `mingw32` suggests you are using a 32-bit compiler, but trying to link 64-bit binaries (as indicated by `x86_64-w64`) to it. If that is the case it cannot work, they both should use the same "bitness"

Comment: @UnholySheep Is "SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\" 32-bit? Using the "SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\" .a files the error is still the same

Comment: I don't think you need all those `-l` and `-L`s.  Those are necessary for dynamic linking (also you can leave off the 'lib' part in the name when linking libraries this way; lib is already implied).  Instead, just pass in the .a file you want to use into the gcc command like you would any other source file.

Comment: I'm not sure if `-l "libmingw32.a"` (and others) are valid, normally you'd write it as `-lmingw32`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons If I don't put the -L it just doesn't find the files but I could shorten the lib names thanks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -l "libmingw32.a" is just another way of writing -lmingw32 and I think it's valid since I get the same error by shortening the names

Comment: *"I also get the classic undefined reference to "winmain""* With SDL this means you're using x64 libraries with a x32 compiler, or vice versa. Try x32 libraries (the `i686` ones), and use the shortened names.

Comment: Also you don't need `-L "C:\__coding\tools\MinGW\lib\"`. `-lmingw32` should work even without it. Also you should update your compiler, GCC 4.8 is *old*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry, exact same error with i686 include/lib and short names.

Comment: Did you get `undefined reference to WinMain` this time? Or was it only `undefined reference to SDL_...`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat WinMain if I didn't use SDL functions inside main(). Anyway removing the line -L "C:\__coding\tools\MinGW\lib\" fixed absolutely everything and I don't really understand why but thanks alot

Comment: My crystal ball says that's because you've copied x64 libraries to `"C:__coding\tools\MinGW\lib\"`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat well done that's exactly what I did at some point